# Can't add a Cordova plugin to my PhoneGap project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins, arduino

I'm new to Phonegap (using CLI to start the project and manage it, and desktop to serve, both running on Windows8),

This is what I've done so far:

```
phonegap plugin add cordovarduino

Fetching plugin "cordovarduino" via npm

Plugin "fr.drangies.cordova.serial" already installed on android. Making it top-
level.

Plugin "fr.drangies.cordova.serial" already installed on browser.
```

On the project;

```
serialMonitor: function(){
        app.debug("Initializing Serial Monitor");
        try {
            //cordova.require("serial.js");
            serial.requestPermission({
                    driver: 'FtdiSerialDriver' // or any other
                },
                function success(){app.debug("Granted access");},
                function error()  {app.debug("Denied access");}
            );

        }catch(err) {
            app.debug("Error: "+ err.message);          
        }


    }
```

In platform/android/res/xml/config.xml:

```
<feature name="Serial">
    <param name="android-package" value="fr.drangies.cordova.serial.Serial" />
</feature>
```

But in platform/browser/res/xml/config.xml, there wasn't added, so I added it manually, as

```
<param name="android-package" value="fr.drangies.cordova.serial.Serial" />
```

and then replaced as

```
<param name="browser-package" value="fr.drangies.cordova.serial.Serial" />
```

Also included cordova.js and called serialMonitor() on ondeviceready event.

But I'm still getting :

```
serial is not defined
```

Maybe is not a bug!, any help please?

Comment: included cordova.js file? Registered ondeviceready event?

Comment: Yup, both things were done. I've started coding from the automatic helloworldish project template (And it runs well). 

To use platform specific plugins, do I need to use something different than PhoneGap Developer App? Do I strictly need to build the apk and deploy it?

Do I need to whitelist or change some config file manually?

Comment: I use Cordova bare bone project to do all this stuff. But you dont need to whitelist until u r trying to communicate through http protocols or anything lik that. Could you post your complete HTML file?

Comment: @Gandhi there was nothing wrong with my code, read my answer for the solution. I was right, some plugins seems to became callable, or get included in the app only on the right platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after struggling against PhoneGap CLI with issues related to Build Tools version, and some other stuff, I've managed to build and deploy on Android the .apk, once there, and ONLY WHEN OTG CABLE WAS PLUGGED AND ARDUINO DETECTED BY ANDROID (info for cordovarduino users), permissions where asked and eureka! "Granted access" was prompt, therefore serial object was found.

## Conclussion:

Yes, **some plugins are ment ONLY to work (became callable) on some platforms**, and PhoneGap Developer App is, correct me if I'm wrong, a browser platform.

So running the compiled apk directly on that platform will allow some plugins to be callable in runtime, otherwise not.

Sorry if this was obvious to many people, but it was my first day on PhoneGap.

Live long and prosper.